# Why is my javascript failing to work?

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

I've been working on this code for a while. The idea is to get javascript to make a div visible based on the results of a HTML form (not on this page). However, my javascript function never works. I've isolated the problem to the script not being called in the first place. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php
While ($result=mysql_fetch_array($data)){ //I have mySQL code before this
        $equipment= $result['safety equipment'];
$equipment2= str_replace(' ', '_', $equipment); //modified equipment name without spaces so that post can read it
            $problem = $_POST[$equipment2];
            ?>
<div style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $equipment?>"> <!--Code that creates a div for each equipment -->
            <h1>Report a problem</h1> <br>
            You reported that there is a problem with the <?php echo $equipment." in ".$name;?>.<br>
            Please describe the problem.
            <form>
                <textarea row="5" column="300" name="Issue">                        
                </textarea>
            </form>
            </div>
            <?php
    if ($problem=="working"){
        inspectRoom($UID,$equipment,null);
    }else {
        echo $equipment; //this part works
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">'; //this part does not work
        echo'console.log("test");';
        echo'var test ='.$equipment.';';
        echo'alert (test);';
        echo'Appear(test);';
        echo'</script>';                    
    }
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Appear(equipment){
            alert("hi"); //error trapping
            document.getElementById(equipment).style.display='block';
        }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

$equipment is a string with the name of the equipment (ex: Fume Hood)
$problem is a string retrieved from the previous page. It too has the name of some equipments.
In my console I get the following error:
"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you doesnt open the <?php tag before while

Comment: What does $equipment contain? Is it possible you should've wrapped it in quotes?

Comment: Please could you share what is actually outputted to the browser? I think there's probably a problem where you're echoing `$equipment` into your Javascript.

Comment: There is no <?php   ?> around your PHP code within HTML contents.

Comment: Please use an IDE to write your code. That will reveal all your basic syntax errors right away.

Answer (score 2):

You're dumping PHP-based text directly into a Javascript context, which is highly dangerous. Any JS metacharacters (especially `'`) will cause syntax errors and kill the entire JS code block.

```
    echo'var test ='.$equipment.';';
```

Should be

```
  echo 'var test = ', json_encode($equipment), This will produce syntactically valid JS code, no matter what's in `$equipment`.
```

Plus, you have MANY other syntax errors. Your php `while` is NOT contained in a `<?php ... ?>` code block, so it'll appear directly in your output as raw text. The html inside your while loop is now considered part of the PHP code, so that'll be yet another syntax error. etc... etc... etc.. In other words this code is utterly broken.

Comment: I used the json_encode as suggested, but my error is now "Appear is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Talking solely about javascript since that's what your question is about, your `Appear` function would never been defined yet since the PHP code would have echoed out the JS that calls `Appear` before the function is defined.

Comment: The problem is that I need to define my function after the div are defined,because of the getElementById part. I guess I could shove my function between the div and the calling, but I would prefer not to have the function defined in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are forgetting the space after echo. There are other errors also such as your while is not within  tags.

Answer (score 0):

For this part of the code

```
    echo $equipment; //this part works
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">'; //this part does not work
    echo'console.log("test");';
    echo'var test ='.$equipment.';';
    echo'alert (test);';
    echo'Appear(test);';
    echo'</script>';
```

Replace it with

```
    echo $equipment; //this part works
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">'; //this part does not work
    echo'console.log("test");';
    echo"var test ='$equipment';";
    echo'alert (test);';
    echo'Appear(test);';
    echo'</script>';
```

Th variable isn't surrounded by quotes when the value will be a string;

Answer (score -1):

To start with you are missing a > on line 6.